Firefox: Session storage memory was lost though the tab was not closed in the old version (v116/v117)
Currently, I use Firefox version: 116.0.2 or v117.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
I encountered a phenomenon like this:
When I logged in to the application, in the tab I was working on, the Firefox session memory was lost (don't open new tabs)
Steps:

Login to the application
Operate on the screen
Navigate to other URLs, but still on this tab
Session storage was lost

What is the cause of this phenomenon? How can I fix it?
Expect: Session storage memory is not lost
